# Outlook Web AddIn - Iframe ADFS sites

Tags: adfs, outlook-web-addins

I’m developing OutlookWebAddIn. In my flow I use iframes. I want to authenticate client and my application uses custom authentication provider based on ADFS. Our authentication page has redirect to ADFS and by default ADFS pages have X-Frame-Options set to sameorigin.
[IFrame screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMPS7.png)
[Console screeen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XB6X.png)

Is there any workaround for displaying such pages as a iframes ?

Answer (score 1):

Most Authentication providers have X-Frame-Options set to same-origin or deny and hence can't be shown on an iframe. Please use the [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) in your web add-in to let users authenticate.